# javascript: prevent nesting of top-level div tags in "content editable" when ctrl-c ctrl-v

Tags: javascript

So i'm working on my fancy html based markdown editor...testing some code i will use to make it.

[image]

1. entered a few lines of text in editable content.
2. selected text using cursor
3. ctrl-c to copy it to the clipboard as html
4. select a place to paste it in the editable content.
5. ctrl-v

PROBLEM: Now I observe that my (div class="md-item")...(/div) are NESTED inside of each other!

how to prevent this from happening??

I want all "md-item" tags to be at the toplevel of the editable content and perfectly flat without nesting.  and i want to preserve the html when pasting without converting to text.

[image]
Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><style>
#container {display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}
#content, #output {border: 1px solid black; min-height: 200px; width: 45%; padding: 5px;}
#output {overflow-wrap: break-word;}
</style></head><body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content" contentEditable="true">
    </div>
            
    <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
            
    <div id="output">
        <!-- HTML will be displayed here -->
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function typeText(element, text) {
    text.split('').forEach((char) => {
        let keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: char, code: char.charCodeAt(0)});
        element.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
        element.textContent += char;
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const content = document.querySelector('#content');
    const output  = document.querySelector('#output');
    const refresh = document.querySelector('#refresh');

    const rawUpdateOutput = () => {
        let formattedText = '';
        document.querySelectorAll('#content > div').forEach((divItem) => {
            formattedText += divItem.outerHTML + '\n';
        });
        let textarea       = document.createElement('textarea');
        textarea.innerHTML = formattedText;
        output.innerText   = textarea.value;
    };

    const updateMdItems = () => {
        let allMdItems = content.querySelectorAll('div');
        allMdItems.forEach(mdItem => {
            // Add 'md-item' class to all divs.
            mdItem.classList.add('md-item');
        });
        
        rawUpdateOutput();
    }

    // Use setInterval to continuously check and modify the structure.
    setInterval(updateMdItems, 1000);

    refresh.addEventListener('click', rawUpdateOutput);

});
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```